# Can we keep Bluetooth low energy (BLE) in iOS running in background?

Tags: ios, iphone, io, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

We are thinking of using the Bluetooth beacons to identify the location of a device even when are our app is not being used by user. Is it possible to run BLE search in background every 5-10 min without switching it on?

Comment: Do you want to use iBeacons or a standard BLE device?  Both options are available in the background. For iBeacons refer to the the Core Location documentation.  For BLE refer to Core Bluetooth.  Both sets of documentation from Apple have information on background operation

Comment: Thanks for quick reply... We want to use standard BLE device (eddystone) without Bluetooth switched on permanently. Will that be possible?

Comment: The user needs to have Bluetooth enabled on their device and your app will need to get background "use always" location permissions from the user.